# Circular block bootstrap (CBB) Value-at-Risk (VаR)

Tags: value-at-risk, bootstrap

I am calculating Value-at-Risk (VAR) with the Circular block bootstrap (CBB) method.

How do I complete the circle and join $P_{10}$ and $P_1$ so that I do not get -70% yield?
If I proceed with CBB VAR without any adjustments, my .99 percentile VAR becomes -70%! That observation is not even real.

[image]

Comment: As you say -70% is not an actual return so it is not included in the calculations, I believe. You have to bootstrap actual returns. To fill a circular buffer with N returns you need N+1 consecutive prices.

Comment: (Your prices also look fishy, with a strong downtrend followed by a strong uptrend. They don't look like a random walk at all. I would love to trade a market so predictable).